# swift - bgMusic - fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, background-music

I've found a bug on my app but only when the app runs on a device, if the app runs using the simulator no error is generated.

I've located the error down to the background music script, the output error is `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. I've looked at similar questions here but found no remedy.

Can anyone help fix my code?

```
    var bgMusicURL:NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("bgMusic", withExtension: "aif")!
    backgroundMusicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: bgMusicURL, error: nil) //error here!!!
    backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
    backgroundMusicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    backgroundMusicPlayer.play()
```

Please let me know if you need more code.

Thank you.

Comment: `error:strong text nil` is not Swift. That cannot be your real code. Show your real code.

Comment: Apologies, that was a typo. edited to correct code.

Comment: Explain exactly how _bgMusic.aif_ is supposed to get into the app bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your bgMusic.aif file added to your target ?

If not it may play ok on the simulator, but not on the device

Answer (score 1):

Double check that the following is not nil on the device:

```
NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("bgMusic", withExtension: "aif")
```

Force unwrapping the failable init of NSURL is asking for a crash. You should bind the value with:

```
if let bgMusicURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("bgMusic", withExtension: "aif") {
    backgroundMusicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: bgMusicURL, error: nil)
    backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
    backgroundMusicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    backgroundMusicPlayer.play()
}
```

Comment: But you are not explaining why it would be nil on the device and not on the simulator.